# Maximizing an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inner-products, maxima-minima, projection

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, $F$ a hyperplane of $E$ and $v \not\in F$ a fixed unit vector. What is the maximum value $\langle x,v \rangle$ can assume when $x$ varies over $F$ and has unit norm?

Geometrically, we are trying to minimize the angle of a unit vector in $F$ with the vector $v$, so my guess is that $x$ has to be parallel to the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $F$. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

It is the norm of the orthogonal projection of $v$ on $F$.

Comment: When $x$ is parallel to the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $F$, right?

Comment: When $x$ is parallel  to the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $F$,  $x$ or $-x$ realize this maximum.

Comment: Yes, but with unit norm.

Comment: How do you know the problem is reduced to finding the projection point? Based your intuition or you have a proof for it?

Comment: Based on my intuition, but I think it can be solved using Lagrange multipliers..